# Pasar variables adicionales a Passport-Twitter

Tags: nodejs, login, twitter

Necesito pasar una variable adicional al *login* con *Twitter* de *passport*, sería algo como esto:

```
app.get('/twitter',
    function (req, res) {
        var variableallegar = req.query.idunico;
    }, passport.authentication('twitter');
    app.get('/twitter/callback', function (req.res) {
        //ACA ME LLEGA EL PERFIL DEL USUARIO
        //quisiera que tambien me llege,
        //variableallegar
});
```

¿Cómo lo podría hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Ojo que tienes un typo en `app.get('/twitter/callback', function (req.res) {`, el req.res deberia ser `req, res`.

Puedes pasar parámetros entre middlewares (cada funcion que le asignas al router) a través del req. Aunque no entiendo muy bien como has asignado ahí los middlewares, prueba de este modo:

```js
app.get('/twitter/callback',
    function (req, res) {
        req.variableallegar = req.query.idunico;
    }, 
    passport.authentication('twitter'), 
    function (req, res) {
        var variableallegar = req.variableallegar;
        //Aunque desde aqui tambien deberias poder acceder a req.query.idunico
    }
);
```